# C# Building Visual Studio Project in Console Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to build my visual studio sln project in code. I am calling the vs 2017 command prompt then trying to send the command Msbuild.  I am getting the following error:

“[ERROR:parse_cmd.bat] Invalid command line argument: 'msbuild'. Argument will be ignored.
[ERROR:parse_cmd.bat] Invalid command line argument: 'projectName.sln'. 
Argument will be ignored.”

Failing at the line `buildInfo.Arguments = "msbuild project.sln";`

```
Process cmd = new Process();
    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo buildInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        buildInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        buildInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        buildInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        buildInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        buildInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        buildInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat";
        buildInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"directoryToProject";
        buildInfo.Arguments = "msbuild project.sln";

        cmd.StartInfo = buildInfo;

        cmd.Start();
        string stderr_str = cmd.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        string stdout_str = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(stderr_str);
        Console.WriteLine(stdout_str);

        cmd.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Close();
      Console.WriteLine("Built the project");
    }
}
```

I expect it to build the sln project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is build, I would recommend changing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat` to the path of MSBuild executable which SHOULD be something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64` And then it should build.